# Cannot execute Java functions/procedures from oracle reports

Tags: java, oracle, java-web-start, oracleforms

The problem I have is that I can execute imported Java functions from Oracle Reports Builder with the preview feature, but when I try to launch the the report from a Java Web Start application I get a Java exception.

I've tried handling this exception the way it is explained here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/452897?start=0&tstart=0.

But the `exception_.getMessage(exc)` function raises the same exception I'm trying to catch.
The oracle exception I get is ORA - 105101.

Any idea on how to approach this is very much appreciated.

Comment: What are those "imported Java functions" supposed to do in a report?

Comment: I use it to generate a QR image (png) in a certain folder and then access the file from the report. The problem is though, that regardless of what the function does, I get the error whenever I try to execute any Java function.